# Haskell 'any' function - primality check

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define an `is_prime` function in Haskell.  Can anyone point out the issue with the use of the any function?

In addition, I know that the below code is naïve, but I am learning the language so starting with babysteps.

```
is_prime 0 = False
is_prime 1 = False
is_prime 2 = True
is_prime n = any [n `mod` k == 0 | k <- [2.. sqrt n]]
```

Comment: Note that, apart from @Jan's fix regarding the use of `any` - by the way, the function that does what you seem to have expected from `any` is called `or` - and the use of `sqrt`, your check is wrong, you're missing a `not`, as is, it would return `True` for composite numbers and `False` for primes (other than 2).

Comment: You could also think of the solution as making a list of all the divisors and checking if that list is null (or not): `null [k | k <- [2..sqrt n], n \`mod\` k == 0]`

Comment: Good question. In this case it wasn't too hard to see the error, but in the future you should probably include an error message, so it is easier to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type of `any` is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`, so it accepts a predicate and a collection. So you should rewrite your last case as for instance

```
is_prime n = not $ any (\k -> n `mod` k /= 0)
                       [2 .. ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n]
```

`fromIntegral` is necessary because `sqrt`'s type is `Floating a => a -> a` while your `n` is an integer. Subsequently, without `ceiling` the second argument of `any` would be `Floating t => [t]`. This would break, as calling `mod`, whose type is `Integral a => a -> a -> a`, on non-integral types is illegal.

If you'd like to look for some other implementations, I can recommend for example [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541415/haskell-prime-test).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is, to my mind, incorrect as the `is_prime` function actually returns `False` if `n` is a prime, and here's why.

1. `any function data` returns `True` as soon as it encounters such an element in `data` that `function data` is `True`.
2. `\k -> mod n k /= 0` returns `True` if applied to a number that *does not* divide some constant `n`.
3. thus, `any` returns `True` if there is a number in the given list that *does not* divide the number `n` we want to check for primality and `False` if there *is* one.
4. so, `is_prime` returns `True` for any number that *is* divisible by any number in the list `[2 .. ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n]`, for example, `4` which clearly *is not* a prime.

With that said, the correct solution should look like this:

```
is_prime n = not $ any (\k -> n `mod` k == 0) [2 .. ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n]
```

This is because a number `n` is prime if it's *not* a multiple of any number between 2 and `sqrt n`.